# Linear Gradient not being displayed in some Android devices

Tags: android, shader, android-view, android-xml, linear-gradients

I am creating a gradient using `LinearGradient` on a `Canvas` object. I am using this gradient by including the class in my main layout XML.

The code for generating the gradient is:

```
public class BackgroundGradient extends View{

    private Resources res;
    private int [] colors;
    private float [] pos;
    private Paint paint;
    private Shader shader;

    public BackgroundGradient(Context context) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public BackgroundGradient(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        super(context,attrs);
        init();
    }

    public BackgroundGradient(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        super(context,attrs,defStyle);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        paint  = new Paint();
        res    = getResources();
        colors = new int[10];
        pos    = new float[10];

        int[] c = { //array of colors };

        float[] p = { //positions };

        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            colors[i] = c[i];
            pos[i]    = p[i];
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        shader = new LinearGradient(0,getHeight(),getWidth(), 0, colors, pos, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
        paint.setShader(shader); 
        canvas.rotate(20, 0, getHeight());
        canvas.drawPaint(paint);
    }
}
```

So, above is the file that I included in my `activity_main.xml` inside a `FrameLayout`.

**activity_main.xml**:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <include layout="@layout/bg_gradient" />

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="5dp"
        android:background="#000"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView android:id="@+id/pager_strip"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="5dp"
            android:background="@color/mu_blue_6"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- other views -->  

</FrameLayout>
```

**bg_gradient.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <FrameLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <!-- 
        <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:text="This is button" />  -->  

        <in.mubpack.b2o.ui.BackgroundGradient
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </FrameLayout>
</merge>
```

I cannot figure out why the gradient is visible in some Android devices and not in others. Can anyone help me?

Comment: what api levels do they use?

Comment: Could you check the Android version/device brand of the devices? This issue seems depend on some factors.

Comment: @pskink i could not understand what exactly are you asking. the minSdkVersion for my project is set for 14 and target for 19.

Comment: @AndrewT. my emulator does not show the gradient for any Android Version. I checked it on Jellybean 4.2 and Kitkat the gradient is visible but on Ice Cream Sandwich 4.0.4 it is not. These are the only devices which I can test on right now

Comment: I just tested your code using Nexus 4, Android 4.4.4 KitKat, and somehow the background wasn't displayed. I toyed around with layer type, and somehow it was displayed if it's not `View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE`. I'm not sure if this is the cause, but maybe it's worth trying it.

Comment: I went through a documentation on **Hardware Acceleration** on the developers site and that is when I had introduced `View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE` into the snippet. Even removing this code has no effect on devices lower than Jellybean (Gradient still doesn't show on them).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok now I think I figured it out. Did a lot of debugging of my code..seems that the `colors` and `pos` arrays that i was using in `LinearGradient` had been initialized for 10 elements while I was using just 8 elements. Dont know why this came up only when I started testing for Ice Cream Sandwich but now it has been resolved. Changes that I made to the code:

```
colors = new int[8]; 
pos = new float[8];
```